# Primefaces picklist target value to populate a separate datatable

Tags: primefaces

Excuse me for posting here and not on the primeFaces forum, but I can't seem to register on their forums (I never get the confirmation email EDIT: note to self: always check the spambox).  I'm using primefaces 2.2RC.  I have a wizard component embedded in a tabbed window component.  The workflow wizard asks the user to pick a material from a .  I want the outcome of that picklist (picklist.target) to populate a .  I see that there is now an onTransfer attribute on picklist but no documentation on how to use it.
The code works and populates the picklist and I can pick strings and advance to the next tab.  I just can't get the updated(?) materials.target list.
Can anyone give a clue?

My code below:

```
<p:tab id="Step3" title="Pick materials">
  <p:panel header="Step 3" >
   <p:pickList value="#{materialPickListBean.materials}" var="mat"
    itemLabel="#{mat}" itemValue="#{mat}" converter="matConverter" onTransfer="">
    <f:facet name="sourceCaption">Available</f:facet>
    <f:facet name="targetCaption">Picked</f:facet>
   </p:pickList>

  </p:panel>
 </p:tab>
 <p:tab id="Step4" title="Adjust material quantites">
  <p:panel header="Step 4">
   <p:dataTable value="#{materialBean.materialList}" var="matList"
    dynamic="true" id="pickedMaterials">
    <f:facet name="header">Select material quantities</f:facet>
    <p:column>
     <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="Material description" />
     </f:facet>
     <h:outputText value="#{matList.name}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
     <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="unit type" />
     </f:facet>
     <h:outputText value="#{matList.unitOfMeasurement}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
     <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="units" />
     </f:facet>
     <h:inputText value="#{matList.quantity}" />
    </p:column>
   </p:dataTable>
   <p:commandButton value="Submit" actionListener="#{jobCardWizard.save}"/>
  </p:panel>
 </p:tab>
```

bean:

```
public void init() {
loginEJB.setupMockMaterial();
source = new ArrayList<String>();
target = new ArrayList<String>();
populateSource();
materials = new DualListModel<String>(source, target);
}

private void populateSource() {
List<Material> materialList = materialEJB.findMaterials();
for (Material m : materialList) {
source.add(m.getName());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public DualListModel<String> getContactsList() {
        return contactsList;
    }

    public void setContactsList(DualListModel<String> contactsList) {
        this.contactsList = contactsList;
    }

public List<String> targetContacts(){
        
        this.selectedContacts = contactsList.getTarget();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I eventually went with the Richfaces implementation of the picklist.  I have both rich and primefaces in the project.